# Why does Sonatype flag jQuery 3.6.0 as having a prototype pollution vulnerability even though it was fixed?

Tags: jquery, sonatype

The sonatype finding says this:

sonatype-2019-0115

> The application is vulnerable by using this component. Certain versions of jQuery (for example 3.4.1 present in NuGet downloads), even if fixed, may continue to report this vulnerability because of the bundled jquery-...vsdoc.js variant still containing vulnerable code. In such cases, you are vulnerable only if the ...-vsdoc.js file is being used directly in your production application.

This issue was resolved with jQuery 3.4.1. How can I tell if a "bundled -vsdoc.js" file is being used? There are no references to it anywhere in the project, I don't see it included in the nuget package, and the only references I can find to the file on google have to do with really old versions of jQuery.

Follow up question, how does someone get into a vulnerable state when using the latest version of jQuery? Basically I'm trying to figure out how to definitively prove that this vulnerability does not affect my program.

Answer (score -1):

You can remove the jQuery from the application by uninstalling the Nuget package.  With Nuget package reference, it will look for jQuery downloads in package folder("applicationrootfoler\packages\jQuery.x.x.x\Content\Scripts") and there is a reference of vsdoc.js file. When build happens in build pipeline, these packages are referred from packages.config. The vulnerability is caused by the code is in the vsdoc.js file. These files were not updated when the fix for prototype vulnerability was applied to the main jQuery files.

In short, do not use the jQuery as Nuget downloaded package. Instead download the jquery version and use it.

Comment: Nuget is there to update and patch packages with updates. Just uninstalling and copying in the js or other package still means that the vulnerability could be there. Overall this doesn't seem like good advice.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: if u see the error message, it states that issue is in the vsdoc.js file. The patch for the fix is already provided for jquery main files. but not in the vsdoc.js files that get downloaded in your packages folder while installing over Nuget package manager. The patch i am talking about is for the prototype pollution in fn.extend method. you can refer to the link where the patch is provided
https://github.com/DanielRuf/snyk-js-jquery-174006/blob/master/jquery-3.3.1.patch

The fix is available in the latest jquery main files